On closing keyboard custom Textfield value us getting cleared
on scrolling or sometime closing keyboard clearing TextFiled value
  class CaratSearchSection extends StatelessWidget {
      final SearchDiamondFormMode searchDiamondFormMode;

  CaratSearchSection({super.key, required this.searchDiamondFormMode});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Range? caratRange;

    const bool isFirstTime = true;

    return Form(
      key: _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).caratRangeItemFormKey,
      child: CoreExpansionTile(
        title: Text(
          context.localizations.carats.capitalizeFirstLetter,
        ),
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child:
                    BlocBuilder<SearchDiamondFormCubit, SearchDiamondFormState>(
                  buildWhen: (oldState, newState) {
                    final oldCaratRangeLength = oldState
                            .diamondSearchParameters.caratRangeItems?.length ??
                        0;
                    final newCaratRangeLength = newState
                            .diamondSearchParameters.caratRangeItems?.length ??
                        0;
                    return (newState.changedParameter == DiamondSearchParameterEnum.carat && newCaratRangeLength > oldCaratRangeLength);
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state.isAllChanged) {
                      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                        _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).minController.clear();
                        _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).maxController.clear();
                      });
                    }
                    return CaratMinMaxFields(
                      onChanged: (newCaratRange) {
                        caratRange = newCaratRange;
                       // addCaratRange(context, caratRange);
                      },
                      minController:  _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).minController,
                      maxController:  _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).maxController,
                      maxValue: getIt<AppSetting>().maxCaratValue.toDouble(),
                      minValue: getIt<AppSetting>().minCaratValue,
                      range: const Range(),
                      isFirstTime: isFirstTime,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              8.width,
              CoreIconButton(
                child: const PhosphorIcon(
                  PhosphorIconsBold.plus,
                  color: CoreColor.neutral900,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  final bool isCaratFormValidated =
                      _searchDiamondFormCubit(context)
                              .caratRangeItemFormKey
                              .currentState!
                              .validate() ==
                          true;
                  if (isCaratFormValidated && caratRange?.isValid == true) {
                    _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).addCaratRange(
                      CaratRangeItem(
                        min: caratRange!.from!.toDouble(),
                        max: caratRange!.to!.toDouble(),
                      ),
                    );
                    dismissKeyboard();
                    _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).maxController.clear();
                    _searchDiamondFormCubit(context).minController.clear();
                    caratRange = null;
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 
  SearchDiamondFormCubit _searchDiamondFormCubit(BuildContext context) =>
      context.read<SearchDiamondFormCubit>();

 
}

This is carat min and max field
class CaratMinMaxFields extends FormField<Range> {
  final String? title;

  /// The minimum allowed value for the range. Defaults to 0.
  final double minValue;

  /// The maximum allowed value for the range. Defaults to 100.
  final double maxValue;

  /// A callback function called when the range values change.
  /// This callback getting triggered does not mean the text field have validated value.
  final ValueChanged<Range?>? onChanged;

  final TextEditingController minController;
  final TextEditingController maxController;
  final AutovalidateMode? validateMode;
  final Range? range;
  static bool _fakeValidator = true;
   bool isFirstTime = true;

  CaratMinMaxFields({
    this.title,
    this.minValue = 0,
    this.maxValue = 100,
    this.onChanged,
    this.validateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    this.range,
    required this.isFirstTime,
    required this.minController,
    required this.maxController,
    super.key,
  }) : super(
          autovalidateMode: validateMode,
          initialValue: range,
          validator: (Range? range) {
             if (_fakeValidator) return null;

            if (range == null || (range.from == null && range.to == null)) {
              return null;
              // return AppRouter.navigatorKey.currentContext?.localizations.enterValueRangeErrorWithString('0.15', '50.00');
            }
            if (range.from == null) {
              return AppRouter.navigatorKey.currentContext?.localizations
                  .fromFieldCannotBeEmpty;
            }

            if (range.to == null) {
              return AppRouter.navigatorKey.currentContext?.localizations
                  .toFieldCannotBeEmpty;
            }

            final isFromGreaterThanTo =
                (range.from ?? double.maxFinite) > (range.to ?? 0);
            final isFromSmallerThanMinValue =
                (range.from ?? double.maxFinite) < minValue;
            final isToGreaterThanMaxValue =
                (range.to ?? double.maxFinite) > maxValue;
            if (isFromGreaterThanTo) {
              return AppRouter.navigatorKey.currentContext?.localizations
                  .minGreaterThanMaxValueError;
            }
            if (isFromSmallerThanMinValue || isToGreaterThanMaxValue) {
              return AppRouter.navigatorKey.currentContext?.localizations
                  .enterValueRangeErrorWithString(
                      minValue.toStringAsFixed(2),
                     maxValue.toStringAsFixed(2));
            }
            return null;
          },
          builder: (FormFieldState<Range> state) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    if (title != null) ...{
                      Text(
                        title,
                        style: CoreTextStyle.sRegular,
                      ),
                      16.height,
                    },
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: CoreLeadingInputField(
                            title: context.localizations.from,
                            controller: minController,
                            hintText: '0.15',
                            onChanged: (value) {

                              _fakeValidator = true;
                              final fromValueInNum =
                                  num.tryParse(value.replaceAll(",", "."));

                              if (fromValueInNum == null) {
                                if (state.value?.to == null) {
                                  state.reset();
                                  state.didChange(const Range());
                                } else {
                                  state.didChange(
                                    (Range(to: state.value?.to)),
                                  );
                                }
                              } else {
                                state.didChange(
                                  (state.value ?? const Range())
                                      .copyWith(from: fromValueInNum),
                                );
                              }
                              state.validate();
                              _fakeValidator = false;
                              onChanged?.call(state.value);
                            },
                            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                              decimal: true,
                            ),
                            textInputFormatter: [
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                twoDecimalPlaceNumber,
                              ),
                            ],
                            hasError: state.hasError,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: CoreLeadingInputField(
                            title: context.localizations.to,
                            controller: maxController,
                            hintText: '50.00',
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              _fakeValidator = true;
                              final toValueInNum =
                                  num.tryParse(value.replaceAll(",", "."));

                              if (toValueInNum == null) {
                                if (state.value?.from == null) {
                                  state.reset();
                                  state.didChange(const Range());
                                } else {
                                  state.didChange(
                                    Range(from: state.value?.from),
                                  );
                                }
                              } else {
                                state.didChange(
                                  (state.value ?? const Range()).copyWith(
                                    to: toValueInNum,
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                              state.validate();
                              _fakeValidator = false;
                              onChanged?.call(state.value);
                            },
                            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                              decimal: true,
                            ),
                            textInputFormatter: [
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                twoDecimalPlaceNumber,
                              ),
                            ],
                            hasError: state.hasError,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    if (state.hasError) ...{
                      4.height,
                      Text(
                        state.errorText!,
                        style: CoreTextStyle.sRegular.copyWith(
                          color: context.colorScheme.error,
                        ),
                      ),
                    },
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );

  @override
  FormFieldState<Range> createState() => CaratMinMaxTextFields();
}

class CaratMinMaxTextFields extends FormFieldState<Range> {
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant FormField<Range> oldWidget) {
    setValue(widget.initialValue);
    validate();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
}


Textfield usually get refresh whenever it get new object reference. In you case Textfield getting new object as range: const Range(). You can create instance out of build method and then try.
Like this
class CaratSearchSection extends StatelessWidget {
      final SearchDiamondFormMode searchDiamondFormMode;

 CaratSearchSection({super.key, required this.searchDiamondFormMode});

   final Range range = Range();      <----------  Create Instance Here.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Range? caratRange;

                      .... your other code goes.....


                     CaratMinMaxFields(
                      onChanged: (newCaratRange) {
                        caratRange = newCaratRange;
                       // addCaratRange(context, caratRange);
                      },
                      range: range,  <-------- use here that instance


still refreshing

Try to print all TextField's Parameter's HashCode and compare all HashCode with previous one. Which HashCode will change, because of that parameter TextField is updating.

i will check and update you
